# ¿Cómo hacer una peticion ajax en Swift?

Tags: ajax, ios, swift

Necesito acceder a una API REST de un cliente, pero, no entiendo cómo se hacen las peticiones ajax en swift... ¿me podrían dar algún ejemplo?

Comment: Si vas a con sumir una api rest esta mal tu pregunta, porque no es ajax. Es consumir WebService rest en swift. Quiza por eso si es que buscaste en internet no encontraste nada. Y ya busque `consumir WebService rest en swift` y salen hasta videotutoriales. Actualiza tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te refieres a consumir servicios de una API, peticiones HTTP?
Puedes utilizar Alamofire que es muy facil de usar o hacerlo con URLSession que provee Swift.
Ejemplo de URLSession:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.apiurl.com")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
    print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))
}
```

url Alamofire: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire